# onStop not being called ... Home button pressed

Tags: android

In my main activity, under onStop, I set myVar = true. In onResume, I check if myVar = true and do something.

If you hit the home button while on my main activity and launch it again from the home screen/app drawer, it works correctly.

If you hit the home button while on a different activity and launch it again from the home screen/app drawer, it brings up the main activity as I have clearTaskOnLaunch="true" set on my main activity and android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" set on my other activities. However, it doesn't appear that it hit onStop in the main activity when the Home button was pressed.

I start the other activities for result. If result code = result_ok or result_canceled, I set myVar = false. But... if the home button is pressed, it shouldn't be setting results and doing the onActivityResult.

Any idea how to solve this?

Edit:

```
above onCreate.. I set startNew = true;
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        startNew = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (startNew) {
            getCurrentDate(0);
            updateDisplay();
            fillData();
        }
    }
```

The only other reference to startNew, is in my onActivityResult method, if an activity that was launched from my main activity returns either result_ok or result_canceled, I set startNew = false.

I'm trying to ensure that every time my app is launched from home screen / app drawer, that it runs those 3 methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move to onPause() because, per the documentation, the onStop() in some situations will not be invoked.

Comment: I changed it to be safe but I've never noticed a difference between the two with what I'm using it for.

Comment: According to the documentation the onStop() is not guaranteed to be invoked, but onPause() is.  Starting on Honeycomb this changes ... onStop() will now be guaranteed to be invoked, but if you want to support devices running earlier version you need to code accordingly:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Per *what* documentation?

Answer (score 1):

What are you attempting to do in onStop? Typically you want to do it in the onPause method. The closer you get to onDestroy in the lifecycle, the less likely it is that the method will be called before your Activity is destroyed to recover memory.

Comment: I've added more details. What I'm doing seems to work the same, onStop, onPause.

Comment: This is difficult to implement in Android due to the stateless nature of Activities. You intentionally have no knowledge of the source of an activity's launch. As such, the best way I have seen to do it is to subclass application, have the flags in there, and update the flags from the subactivity's finish method. That way, if you launch from the tray, there is no subactivity and, thus, the flags remain at their original state. If the subactivity finishes, the flags are set, and you know that you do not need to refire your methods. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to know where it was launched from. I just need to ensure those 3 methods are hit everytime the main activity comes into view except for when it comes into view as a result of an activity that I started for result, setResult and finishes.  The only time it doesn't work is when the home button is pressed while not in the main activity.

Comment: don't necessarily need to know where it was launched from. I just need to ensure those 3 methods are hit everytime the main activity comes into view except for when it comes into view as a result of an activity that I started for result -- This means you need to know why your activity came into view. It's really the same difference.