# First Activity not stopped when Second Activity started

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

As per Android activity life cycle, when activity is no longer visible `onStop` will get called. But this is not happening, if i exit the second activity quickly.

I have two activities `HomeActivity` and `DetailActivity`.

Step 1. Pressing a button on `HomeActivity` navigates to `DetailActivity`

Step 2. Back press on `DetailActivity` navigates to `HomeActivity`

When navigates to `DetailActivity` , the `onStop` of `HomeActivity` should get called as per activity life cycle, since the `DetailActivity` gets `onStart`.
But `onStop` is not getting called if i back press on `DetailActivity` quickly.

Activity life cycle if back pressed immediately..

```
HomeActivity: onPause
DetailActivity: onStart
DetailActivity: onResume
DetailActivity: onPostResume
DetailActivity: onPause
HomeActivity: onResume
HomeActivity: onPostResume
DetailActivity: onStop
```

Activity life cycle if back pressed after a delay (say few seconds later on DetailActivity)

```
HomeActivity: onPause
DetailActivity: onStart
DetailActivity: onResume
DetailActivity: onPostResume
HomeActivity: onStop
DetailActivity: onPause
HomeActivity: onStart
HomeActivity: onResume
HomeActivity: onPostResume
DetailActivity: onStop
```

Doesn't this look like a bug as new `Activity` is Started, the previous activity  is not stopped?

Comment: If you don't finish the first activity it will keep in background, only the onPause method will be triggered. It is the normal behaviour, use finish() right after startActivity(...)

Comment: @Chol- No thats not. The `HomeActivity` is getting `onStop` if the back press is not quick on `DetailActivity` . Issue is only if you press back immediately

Comment: unless the  previous activity is not totally invisible .

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625428/onstop-not-being-called-home-button-pressed

Comment: Read this : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: @Chol - I read that answers, "the onStop() in some situations will not be invoked"  . What some situation is that i'm trying to understand?

Comment: Don't really know, I think it is handle by android itself, not sure we can do something

Comment: "some situations" -- such as going back to the activity quickly. You discovered one!

Comment: According to the documentation, onStop() gets called when the activity is no longer visible and completely hidden from the user. Seems like navigating back immediately from another activity is a great way to ensure the conditions that trigger onStop() never happen. Why are you surprised?

Comment: @323go that only applied to onStop pre-honeycomb. The OP hasn't indicated which version is in use. In any case, what's described here is normal behavior of onStop, but pre and post honeycomb. No "some situation" (being low on memory, phone about to shut down) here.

Comment: @iheanyi - Back press is not the only scenario this happens. It also happens in case you press a button on `DetailActivity` and navigate to `HomeActivity` Doesn't it mean if i'm able to interact with the second activity (tapping a button) the activity is completely started and the first one should stop?

Comment: @Libin onStop() called when the activity is no longer **visible** not when another activity is running.

Comment: @iheanyi . Yes, but here, a new activity is visible, doesn't that mean the previous activity is invisible?

Comment: @Libin No. Just because a new activity is visible doesn't mean the previous one is invisible. The simplest example of this is that the previous activity takes up an entire screen while the new one only uses a small window in the middle.

Comment: I've also updated my answer to point out a case where this could happen even if the old activity is completely hidden.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) about stopping and restart of an Activity

> The user performs an action in your app that starts a new activity. The current activity is stopped when the second activity is created. If the user then presses the Back button, the first activity is restarted.

They should update it to say `If the user the presses the Back button but not to quickly` haha, but I think [iheanyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250588/iheanyi) is right in the fact that  some other process may have been granted cpu time after the DetailsActivity hit `onPostResume` and the back button was pressed before the OS could continue with the `onStop` process of the HomeAcitvity

Answer (score -1):

You've described normal behavior. Here's what https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle says about this:

> Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because
>   another activity has been resumed and is covering this one. This may
>   happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one
>   is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.
>   Followed by either onRestart() if this activity is coming back to
>   interact with the user, or onDestroy() if this activity is going away.

So, you may be wondering, well, if my new activity is visible, doesn't that mean the previous activity is invisible? Not really. Your new activity may not completely overlap the old one (in which case, part of the old is still visible). This could be especially tricky if the old activity has elements that while "invisible" to the user because they look the same as elements from the new activity, are technically still visible (in that they're not completely blocked by the new).

Visibility aside, you could also inadvertently have lifecycle methods timing issues which lead to this. Let's say your onPause() takes a long time to complete. The other activity could completely hide the old, satisfying the conditions for onStop(), but you transition back before onStop() has a chance to run.

Finally, there are many tasks that need to run on the phone and few processors to execute them. Necessarily, some tasks will have higher priority than others. Think about the code that must execute when your new activity is taking over the foreground - there is no way that onStop() has time to run if the phone is busy executing code for your activity. If that code then triggers onResume, onStop would be skipped altogether.

As you can see from the life cycle diagram, you can transition from onPause() back to onResume() without going through onStop(). Perhaps you should think about the scenarios where something like that can happen (and why) to better understand your particular case.

Comment: Both my activities are full screen layout, so not an issue with "may not completely overlap the old one".  I don't execute anything on `onPause` other than a log.  It sounds like if activity goes to onStart it needs to be alive for few seconds before moving to onPause, if not the previous activity wont get `onStop`. This seems to be a bug for me,, thats why i'm unclear

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's a bug. It seems like you have a simple (and incorrect) view of how the OS works. Essentially, your two activities are not the only things running on a given phone and they don't necessarily have equal priority (or chance of getting execution time). There are lots of things that need to run and a much smaller number of CPUs to run them. Necessarily, some tasks will get higher priority than others. So, you shouldn't expect that onStop() will get called the instant the activity becomes hidden. What you're seeing is what you should expect.

Comment: @libin take a look at the life cycle diagram. As you can see, you can go from onPause() back to onResume() without going through onStop(). Yous seem to think that you're guaranteed to hit onStop() after a onPause().

Comment: I'm not expecting that  'onStop` will always get called after 'onPause' . I'm thinking that when an activity get `onResume`(visible to user to interact) , the previous activity should get `onStop` , thats the problem here.

Comment: @Libin I can understand why you may have that expectation, but that's not behavior specified by the documentation.